# Why doesn't Android intern string resources?

Tags: java, android, string

At least it appears that they do not. If I have the following

```
<string name="bathrooms">Baths</string>
```

the result of this

```
(getString(R.string.bathrooms) == "Baths")
```

is `false`.

It seems strange to me as literals are interned as they are known at compile time. Surely it should be the same for the resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As resources can be language dependent (for example) it makes sense to load them at run time.

Comment: and device dependant as well. This makes sense.

Comment: Ya.. This expalins why the string resources are loaded at run-time.. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You define `<string name="bathrooms">Baths</string>` in an `xml` file. The string `Baths` is created during run-time. So `==` will fail.

Comment: So when you call `getString`, it actually deserialises the xml to get the value?

Comment: @DavidPilkington: How you know `R.string.bathrooms` is Literal?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I dont, if you read my question it states `It seems strange to me as literals are interned as they are known at compile time. Surely it should be the same for the resources?`

Comment: @DavidPilkington - Why do you expect `Baths` to be interned?. It is not a *literal*

Comment: @TheLostMind  reason that I expect it is that is it known at compile time, just like literals. I am not assuming that it is a literal as I know that it is not. Does Android not compile resource files? Or does it simply leave it as a lookup to use later in execution

Comment: @DavidPilkington - A simple test. call `(getString(R.string.bathrooms)` twice and print the `IdentityHashCode`. we will get to know the answer

Comment: Android resources are not compiled!